# JAVA_HOME is invalid (cordova) error

Tags: java, android, wordpress, cordova, ionic3

I have been experiencing this error for the past 7 days. I have researched various helps online but all to no avail:

I am using windows 10, 4gb RAM, 32 bit.

**(node:2240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed. 
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads. Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172**

What should I do?

Comment: to check jdk install or not type  "javac" in cmd. if jdk proper install then return list of command else give error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `JAVA_HOME` path have space for the value `Program Files`,you need add `"` to wrap it

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
```

Comment: @IkehHenry how do you test it,from cmd or IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this info can be usefull... this is a resume from many threads I read on Internet...

I have Windows 10 x64

Previously I installed JRE, JDK and Android Studio.

[Here is where you can find Android SDK path on your system after install Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJd0i.png)

After to set on system enviroments vars `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` (with android sdk path), then I added to `path` var the following:

- `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
- `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools`

Now You could run `cordova run android` and `cordova build android` commands from `cmd.exe` console.

> From Git Bash `MINGW64` I always have your error.

[My System Enviroments vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBrhh.png)

[My system `path` var configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoZOB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your environement vars install Java JDK and go to C:\Program\Java\YourJDK and copy path for add on Env

check here [Java Help JAVA_HOME](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: I did not understand your suggestion

Comment: OK javac was not found so you simply added the variable Manually. or by downloading Java JDK

Comment: I am also getting this issue when I tried to reinstall  new jdk
**Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception occured. Program will exit.**

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the jdk folder? Btw check this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/ Maybe you just need update your path as the article said in the step 4.

Comment: I followed step 5, but I run java -version in my CMD it brought this errow 

C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap